# Server does not return JSON

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, metronic, laravel-datatables

In development, the server returns JSON. But in production it does not return JSON. I found that in production, browser does not send `X-Requested-With` header.

**In development** - Note the `X-Requested-With` header

[image]

**In production** - There is no `X-Requested-With` header

[image]

## Question

How can I make sure the browser sends `X-Requested-With` header always?

Please let me know any direction/ideas to consider...

## Notes

- Laravel app with Metronic theme
- Production Fargate instance is behind a AWS ALB
- In development I use a container (Here it works/Returns JSON)

## What I have found so far

- This is nothing to do with CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) as this is all same/single origin.
- If I add `X-Requested-With` header using Requestly (https://requestly.com/) it returns JSON as expected. (But I can't ask all users to install Requestly)

In below requests, the first one does not return JSON. But when I add `X-Requested-With` header using Requestly, the third request returns JSON.

[image]

Comment: have you checked AWS ALB if it's forwarding all headers correctly?

Comment: thanks @krisgjika for your input. I'll check with devops about this AWS ALB header forwarding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very good chance that AWS ALB is dropping the `X-Requested-With` header since it's a non-standard header.

You can create a middleware that adds the header to the incoming request, for example:

```
class EnsureThatXRequestedWithHeaderExists
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $request->headers->set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

However, since you're seeking a JSON response, I think that a better approach would be to return a JSON response from within your API endpoint. This can be done using the `json()` method as follows:

```
return response->json($data);
```

This way, you don't need to rely on the `X-Requested-With` header at all.

Comment: I think this should work. I'll mark this as answer after testing. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it works fine for you.

Comment: It worked! I just wrapped it with `if (str_contains($request->getRequestUri(), '/user-management/users?draw='))` to limit this only to the url which has the issue. Thanks.

Comment: You're more than welcome